Undefined symbols when using -Onone optimization level in Xcode 16
I am encountering a linker error when building my project with the No Optimization (-Onone) option in Xcode 16. The project compiles and runs fine with the Optimize for Speed (-O) option, but when I switch to -Onone for debugging purposes, I get the following errors:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_allphone_search_init", referenced from:
      _ps_set_allphone_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
      _ps_set_allphone in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_recode in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_jsgf_build_fsg", referenced from:
      _ps_set_jsgf_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_jsgf_get_rule", referenced from:
      _ps_set_jsgf_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_jsgf_parse_file", referenced from:
      _ps_set_jsgf_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_jsgf_rule_iter", referenced from:
      _ps_set_jsgf_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_jsgf_rule_public", referenced from:
      _ps_set_jsgf_file in libvoice.a[arm64][33](pocketsphinx.o)
  "_ngram_model_arpa_read", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_read in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
      _ngram_model_read in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_ngram_model_arpa_write", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_write in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_ngram_model_dmp_read", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_read in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
      _ngram_model_read in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
  "_ngram_model_dmp_write", referenced from:
      _ngram_model_write in libvoice.a[arm64][60](ngram_model.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The undefined symbols are related to an old .a file (written in C++) that has been included in my project for years without any issue. The .a file is statically linked via the Link Binary With Libraries phase in the project settings. This problem started appearing after upgrading to Xcode 16. Previously, both optimization levels (-O and -Onone) worked fine.
While I can compile with optimizations enabled, I frequently need -Onone for debugging purposes to properly inspect variable values. I’d appreciate any insights into why this issue is occurring and how to resolve it.
What I’ve Tried:
Cleaned the build folder and deleted derived data.
Verified the .a file path in Library Search Paths.
Checked that the .a file is correctly linked in the project settings.


I'm using Macbook Air M1.
